# Difference between fs.readFile and fs.createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, fs

Apart from having syntax differences, are there any differences between them in mechanism of reading a file or performance?

Does `readFile` use different mechanism unlike the `createReadStream` which transfers the data `chunks` from source to destination,

Comment: if I am not wrong readFile will read entire file contents

Comment: check the below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459334/what-is-difference-between-file-reading-and-streaming